# Is a compact a finite union of interval $[a,b]$ or a countable union of interval $[a,b]$.

Tags: general-topology

Does every compact set of $\mathbb R$ is a finite union of interval of the form $[a,b]$ ? And if no, is it a countable union of interval of the form $[a,b]$. I thing that the second assertion is true since but I'm not allowed to say if the first one is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Consider the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). It is not a finite or countable union of closed intervals. That is because every closed interval contains nonempty interior, but the Cantor set has no interior.

You might include $\{a\}=[a,a]$ as closed interval. However, even that sense, the Cantor set is not a countable union of closed intervals. If it can be represented as an union of countable many closed intervals, each intervals should be a singleton by above argument. However the Cantor set is uncountable whereas a countable union of finite sets is also countable.

Answer (score 1):

Neither a finite union nor a countable union since [the cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is compact and an uncountable union of singleton.